# Why can’t mathematica find this residue?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, series-expansion

I am trying to find the residue of the function $$f(z)=(z+1)^2e^{3/z^2}$$
at $z=0$. 
I tried the following in Mathematica

```
Residue[(z+1)^2*Exp[3/z^2],{z,0}]
```

which remains unevaluated. Computing this by hand gives the value of $6$. What is going on?

I’ve noticed that Mathematica has a problem with the Laurent series of $e^{3/z^2}$ at $z=0$.

Comment: From the "Possible Issues" section of the [documentation on `Residue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue.html): "Residues are not defined at branch points". Isn't $0$ a branch point for your function?

Comment: @MarcoB does not look like a branch point to me.

Comment: It's an essential singularity.

Comment: I don’t think it is a branch point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) instead:

```
SeriesCoefficient[(z+1)^2 Exp[3/z^2], {z, 0, -1}]
```

> 6

**Addendum**

Another possibility is to note that the residue at 0 and the residue at infinity must sum to zero, since they are the only singularities of the function. Hence we can do:

```
- Residue[(z + 1)^2 Exp[3/z^2], {z, Infinity}]
```

> 6

which is the same answer as before.

Comment: First does not work on Exp[z - 1/z]. Instead you can use a package ContourIntegration.m by Robert Kragler.

Answer (score 7):

Or integrate around zero

```
Integrate[(z + 1)^2 Exp[3/z^2], {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 
    1}]/(2 Pi I) // Simplify

(*   6   *)
```