# How to find the residue of $x^e/e^2$ at $e=0$ through contour integration in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to compute the residue of $\frac{x^\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}=\frac1{\epsilon^2}e^{\epsilon\log x}=\frac1{\epsilon^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\epsilon^k\log^kx$ using Mathematica. A simple Laurent expansion / residue

```
{Normal@Series[x^e/e^2, {e,0,0}], Residue[x^e/e^2, {e,0}]}
```

yields

```
{1/e^2+Log[x]/e+Log[x]^2/2, Log[x]}
```

However, I can't seem to realize this operation using `Integrate`. I have tried several versions, but none would work.

- Version 1: Direct contour integration yields 0. But this *should* work, as it does for simpler functions or at specific values of `x`:

  ```
  Integrate[(x^e/e^2 /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}]
  (* output: 0 *)

  Integrate[(  1/e   /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}]
  (* output: 2*I*Pi *)

  Integrate[(2^e/e^2 /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}]
  (* output: I*Pi*Log[4] *)

  Integrate[(I^e/e^2 /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}]
  (* output: -Pi^2 *)
  ```
- Version 2: I thought about the possible issue concerning the allowed range of `x`. In particular, I checked when the function `x^e/e^2` is recognized as meromorphic:

  ```
  FunctionMeromorphic[x^e/e^2, e]
  (* output: True, if Im[x]!=0 && x!=0 *)
  ```

  I then tried to impose these assumptions by hand, but `Integrate` wouldn't budge:

  ```
  Assuming[Im[x]!=0 && x!=0, Integrate[(x^e/e^2 /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}]]
  (* output: 0 *)

  Integrate[(x^e/e^2 /. e->Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t,0,2*Pi}, Assumptions->(Im[x]!=0 && x!=0)]
  (* output: 0 *)
  ```
- I found [this powerful method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172313/87556) that manually implements the contour integration. Although I didn't find this usage in the `Integrate` documentation and @Akku14 didn't provide an explanation, after playing with the command a little, I realized that the code in that particular example force Mathematica to integrate along the contour $1\rightarrow i\rightarrow-1\rightarrow -i\rightarrow 1$. So, I tried this too:

  ```
  Integrate[x^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]
  ```

  which (after about 25 seconds) yields a lengthy conditional expression. However, `FullSimplify` shows the output is actually 0:

  ```
  Integrate[x^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}] //FullSimplify
  (* output: 0, if Arg[x]>=0 && (Log[x]<0 || Arg[x]<=0) && Re[Log[x]]<0 *)
  ```

So now I'm completely at loss. Is there a way to make `Integrate` behave as it should and always yield the correct answer? Or, could someone explain why `Integrate` behaves in such a mysterious way, so that I would know when `Integrate` could not be trusted?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For a simple version of this observation, set `f[x_,assps_:{}]:=Integrate[x^Exp[I*t],{t,0,2*Pi},Assumptions->assps]`. Then `f[1]` gives `2*Pi`, but `f[x]` gives `0`.  With assumptions, `f[x,x>1]` gives `2*Pi`, but `f[x,x>=1]` gives `0`. With upper integration limit equal to a symbol `a`, the input `Integrate[x^Exp[I*t],{t,0,a}]` gives `I*(ExpIntegralEi[Log[x]]-ExpIntegralEi[E^(I*a)*Log[x]])` which may explain why for `a=2*Pi` we sometimes get `0`, and suggests that the problem has to do with the branch cut of `ExpIntegralEi`, as was probably clear to experienced people here. Version 12.3.

Comment: At least, integration correctly works for concrete `x`, e.g. `Integrate[(Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[I]] + 1/Pi*I)^e/e^2 /. 
  e -> Exp[I*t]*I*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]` results in `\[Pi] Log[Sqrt[2 - (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]] + I/\[Pi]]^2`.

Comment: The required formula can be derived in such a way: `(FindSequenceFunction[
   Table[Integrate[
     Exp[y*e]/e^2 /.    e -> Exp[I*t]*I*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}], {y, 
     1, 10}], y]) /. y -> Log[x]`.

Comment: @user64494 what an interesting solution! Although this is not what I'm looking for in this particular case (the actual problems I want to tackle are much harder than the toy example in the question and don't have closed formulas), this way of thinking will definitely help me in the future!

Comment: @user293787 aha, so the problem with branch cuts is much subtler than I imagined. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess this means ```Series``` is easier to use than ```Integrate``` in these situations.

Comment: Dear @chaostang, for every fixed $x \neq 0$, your function does not have a branch cut as a function of $\epsilon$. You are completely right to point out that these integrals are not handled correctly by Mathematica. In my other comment, I just wanted to give an even simpler example that illustrates the problem that you found, to support your point that there is an issue here.

Comment: This is a complex function of two variables. Why are you surprised it cannot do it?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Mathematically speaking, isn't it possible to treat $x$ as a parameter? I would hope that after imposing certain ```Assumptions```, Mathematica would "treat $x$ as a parameter" as I do :)

Answer (score 6):

Partial result, somehow suggested to my mind by Silvia's answer (started with `x > 0`):

```
Integrate[(x^e/e^2 /. e -> Exp[I*t])*I*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> (x > 1)]

(*  2 I π Log[x]  *)
```

The result seems to depend on the system:

```
$Version
(*  "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"  *)
```

Comment: Hmm... You code evaluates to `I Pi Log[x]` on my side, Windows, in both 13.0.1 and 13.1.

Comment: @Silvia I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnX8D.png, "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Comment: OTOH I got this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD3jm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD3jm.png) . Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: FYI I have filed the bug report. (issue #2242)

Comment: Linux (wolframcloud) prints 0. And so does my windows, 13.1.

Comment: @Silvia Can you try windows 13.1 again on a clean kernel?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Yes I tried, the result is the same.

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit

From the tracing log I see a one step deeper disagreement from this function:

```
(*
Evaluating this to load FunctionProperties`Singularities :
FunctionSingularities[Sin[1/x], x];
*)

FunctionProperties`Singularities[x^e/e^2,{e},{"ALL","LOCAN"}]
(* {{{Im[x]==0,Re[x]<=0}},{},{{e==0,True}},{},{{x==0,True}}} *)
```

V.S.

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[(64781+52253 I)^e/e^2,{e},{"ALL","LOCAN"}]
(* {{},{},{{e==0,True}},{},{}} *)
```

I ***guess***, the first element of the result indicates positions of *branch cuts*, and the last element indicates *branch points*. (The 2nd hard boundaries by definition, the 3rd removable singularities and poles, the 4th essential singularities, etc.) And I ***guess***, in the former case, maybe `` FunctionProperties`Singularities `` is not supposed to consider conditions on `x`.

An evidence of observation:

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b], {a}, {"ALL", "LOCAN"}]
(* {{{Im[a]==0,Re[a]<=0}},{},{},{},{{a==0,True}}} *)
```

V.S.

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b], {a, b}, {"ALL", "LOCAN"}]
(* {{{Im[a]==0,Re[a]<=0},{Im[b]==0,Re[b]<=0}},{},{},{},{{a==0,True},{b==0,True}}} *)
```

---

Regarding the explicit contour integration method, If we compare the computing process between

```
(* 64781 and 52253 are just two random primes for more readable tracing log. *)
Trace[Integrate[(64781 + 52253 I)^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}], TraceInternal -> True, TraceDepth -> 10]
```

and

```
Trace[TimeConstrained[Integrate[x^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}], 0.002], TraceInternal -> True, TraceDepth -> 10]
```

We can see the disagreement happens when computing the following steps:

```
Reduce`RootsAndPoles[(64781 + 52253 I)^e/e^2, e, {-1 - I, 1 + I}, False]
(* {{0, -2}} *)
```

V.S.

```
Reduce`RootsAndPoles[x^e/e^2, e, {-1 - I, 1 + I}, False]
(* $Failed *)
```

If we know for sure $0$ is a pole of multiplicity 2 of $x^e/e^2$ (*Is it?* -- my math knowledge is rusty, I can't confirm or disprove the claim.), we can help `Integrate` to overcome the difficulty:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Reduce`RootsAndPoles}
 , Unprotect[Reduce`RootsAndPoles]
 ; Reduce`RootsAndPoles[x^e/e^2, e, {-1 - I, 1 + I}, False] := {{0, -2}}
 ; Integrate[x^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]
 ]
(* 2 I Pi Log[x] *)
```

Comment: In high school, I used to substitute letters for numeric coefficients. In grad school, I began to reverse it and use the random primes method. :) (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can't remember any bits of complex analysis any more, but I do know how to trace in M! :D

Comment: Nevermind my now-deleted comment. Mixed up the signs...

Comment: We know it is a pole because the limit in 0 for this function of two variables is infinity, while for e^2/x^e it is 0. So it is a pole for any x. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity#Alternative_descriptions Then we can apply some formula, but I do not know one for two variable complex function.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Thanks for reminding me the lost (to me) knowledge! :) I'll add some more observations from the tracing log.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. Both limits exist, so there is a remuvable singularity only there. Again, I dunno about how the formula to find an order of a pole for a two variable function would look like.

Comment: Seems like I still have much to learn regarding debugging in Mathematica :)

Comment: @chaostang Thanks! This is [not the first time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55262/17) I found `Trace` being a handy tool for debugging symbolic computing! :)

Comment: Well, it is not a pole, so 0 is correct.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников What did you mean by "Both limits exist"? doesn't `Limit[x^e/e^2, e -> 0]` gives ∞?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I though it is only Indeterminate that counts but in reality both do. The main definition is given here in comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063894/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singularity-and-a-pole and obviously requires a modulus. So I was right originally, it is a pole, and 1/f is zero. Will fix wikipedia. God.

Comment: BTW, Limit[x^e/e^2, e -> 0, Direction->Complexes] prints ComplexInfinity. And it does appear to be working. Classic example is x^4/Abs[x^4] at x->0. Limit over complexes does not exist, but over Reals it is 1.

Answer (score 5):

A different approach, assuming the residue is a twice differentiable function of `x`: We apply the operator
$$
{d\over dx} x {d\over dx}\ \bullet
$$
to $y(x) = F(x)$, where $F$ is the integral in question, and use `DSolve` to solve for $y(x)$:

```
F[x_] := Inactive[Integrate][x^e/e^2, {e, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}];

DSolve[{
  Activate[
   D[x*y'[x] == F'[x] /. 
     Inactive[Integrate][f_, path_] :> Inactive[Integrate][x*f, path],
     x]
   ],
  y[1] == F[1] // Activate,
  y[2] == F[2] // Activate},
 y[x], x]

(*  {{y[x] -> 2 I π Log[x]}}  *)
```