# What is the status of ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints and ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts?

Tags: complex, analysis

In 13.3 and I believe quite a few versions earlier I could perform

```
 ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[Sqrt[z^2 - 1], z] and

 ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts[Sqrt[z^2 - 1], z]
```

The functions seem undocumented.

What is their status? Are they there just to support other Complex Analysis functions? Or will they become mainstream available soon, what do you think? If you have any (preliminary) documentation, please provide.

Comment: I'd like to notice that `ComplexAnalysis'BranchPoints[Sqrt[z^(9/2) - 1], z]`  and `ComplexAnalysis ' BranchCuts[Sqrt[z^(9/2) - 1], z]` are much stronger than  their Maple's analogs. However I have got  a problem with plotting the result of the latter.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something in the Graphics Guide. I found how to visualize Riemann surfaces in that guide. - I was tipped by Bing Chat.

Comment: FYI [there is also ``FunctionProperties`Singularities``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271955/17).

Comment: @Silvia While it might be tempting to think that singularities must always be branch points, it is not true in general.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137633/1280840

Comment: @lotus2019 That's surely correct. I just wanted to bring up a function of related topic, no further implies intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think those commands leave much to be desired at the present. For example,

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[Sqrt[z^(9/2) - 1], z]
```

> `{0, 1, -(-1)^(1/9), (-1)^(2/9), -(-1)^(1/3), (-1)^( 4/9), -(-1)^(5/9), (-1)^(2/3), -(-1)^(7/9), (-1)^( 8/9), ComplexInfinity}`

If I am not mistaken, the above result is not true. The function under consideration has its branch points at `0`, where `z^(9/2)` has, and at the roots of `z(9/2)==1`. But

```
Reduce[z^(9/2) == 1, z]
```

> `z == 1 || z == -(-1)^(1/9) || z == (-1)^(4/9) || z == -(-1)^(5/9) ||  z == (-1)^(8/9)`

Not taking into account `ComplexInfinity`, we see only 6 branch points, not 10 ones.

Comment: One more bug : `ComplexAnalysis'BranchPoints[Cos[Sqrt[z]], z]` results in `{0}` though `Cos[Sqrt[z]]` is known to be an entire function.

Comment: Are there any good examples?? Or is it all broken?

Answer (score 0):

When the function ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints operates on radical functions, it often mistakenly treats ComplexInfinity or 0 as branch points. In such cases, it is necessary to validate or exclude them based on the definition of branch points, for example:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = Sqrt[(z - a)*(z + b)];
pts = Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[expr, z]]
```

(* {a, -b, ComplexInfinity} *)

According to the definition of branch points (  https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Branch_point  ;

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchPoint.html ):

```
expr1 = Sqrt[(r  Exp[I  \[Theta]] - a)*(r  Exp[I  \[Theta]] + b)]
expr2 = Simplify[expr1 /. {\[Theta] -> \[Theta] + 2  \[Pi]}]
expr1 == expr2
```

(* True *)

Therefore, ComplexInfinity is not a branch point.

While it might be tempting to think that singularities must always be branch points, it is not true in general. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137633/1280840

It is necessary to revise the code of ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints from the perspective of the branch point definition, or develop a new universally applicable function for determining the branch point.

Comment: You wrote "According to the definition of branch points". Can you give us an accessible reference to that definition?

Comment: I think you have to be a bit more careful when you use Mathematica for this type work. It's not using global analytic functions, but functions with branch cuts. For instance, subbing `expr1 = Sqrt[r   Exp[I   \[Theta]]]` into your example yields `True`. In fact, probably for every function, `f[r   Exp[I   \[Theta]]] /. {\[Theta] -> \[Theta] + 2   \[Pi]}]`  yields `f[r   Exp[I   \[Theta]]]`.

Comment: @Goofy You are right, and I may have made a mistake in my examples. I provided two correct examples in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/296769/69835.

Comment: How do you define "Radical Function" ?