# How to verify that a certain point is a branch point for a complex function using Mathematica?

Tags: complex

It is straightforward to verify that `z=0` is a branch point for `w[z]=Sqrt[z]`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

expr1 = Sqrt[r  Exp[I  θ]] /. {θ -> α} // PowerExpand // Simplify

expr2 = Limit[Sqrt[r  Exp[I  θ]] /. {θ -> α + ε π}, ε -> 2, Direction -> "FromBelow"] // PowerExpand // Simplify

Simplify[expr1 - expr2]
```

(*  2 E^((I α)/2) Sqrt[r] *)

And `z=0` is a branch point for `w[z]=Log[z]`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

expr1 = Log[r  Exp[I  θ]] /. {θ -> α} // PowerExpand // Simplify

expr2 = Limit[Log[r  Exp[ I  θ]] /. {θ -> α + ε π}, ε -> 2, Direction -> "FromBelow"] // PowerExpand // Simplify

Simplify[expr1 - expr2]
```

(*  -2 I π *)

However, for some more complex functions, verification is not straightforward. For example, for `z = (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2`, it is challenging to confirm that it is a branch point of `w[z] = Log[-1/+1]`, or that `z = a` is a branch point of `Sqrt[(z-a) (z+b)]`.

How can we write Mathematica (MMA) code to determine, for any given complex function `w[z]`, how `w[z]` changes when `z` encircles any point in the z-plane counterclockwise along a small circle of infinitesimal radius, say, by one revolution (`2 Pi`)? This would help identify whether the point is a branch point.

**EDIT**
I am aware that the function ComplexAnalysis'BranchPoints can be used to find branch points, but sometimes the branch points obtained by this function are incorrect( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289606/69835 ). Moreover, it is not the case that branch points cannot be found outside of this function. One approach is to first find the zeros and singular points (using specialized functions and code), and then systematically check whether these zeros and singular points satisfy the definition of branch points ( https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchPoint.html ) through a program. My question is how to programmatically check whether these zeros and singular points meet the definition of branch points, in order to make decisions and ultimately obtain all branch points.

The approach to finding the branch points of a complex function `w[z]` using MMA programming is as follows: first, determine all the zeros and singular points of `w[z]`. Then, for each of these points, compare whether the following two complex numbers are equal: the complex numbers centered at the point (e.g., point `A`)), denoted as `z1-A` and `z2-A`, with equal magnitudes and infinitesimally small, and where the argument of `z1-A` is 0, and the argument of `z2-A` is `2 Pi` (`Limit->2 Pi`). If these two complex numbers are not equal, the point `A` is identified as a branch point.

Comment: It is not a good practice to subststantially change the question (`Log[(z - 1)/(z + 1)],` is replaced by `Log[-1/+1]`), not indicating the change.

Comment: Please provide a few cases for which `ComplexAnalysis BranchPoints` gives incorrect results.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289606/69835

Comment: You wrote in your EDIT "and then systematically check whether these zeros and singular points satisfy the definition of branch points through a program". Can you kindly elaborate that statement, especially the definition of a branch point?  How from `Simplify[expr1 - expr2]` do you derive that `z==0` is a branch point? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchPoint.html

Comment: Sorry, the fuzzy desciption there is based on Arfken, G. Mathematical Methods for Physicists, 3rd ed. Orlando, FL: Academic Press, pp. 397-399, 1985 and
Morse, P. M. and Feshbach, H. Methods of Theoretical Physics, Part I. New York: McGraw-Hill, pp. 391-392 and 399-401, 1953. [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Branch_point) uses   Puiseux series and Riemann surfaces to this end.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) uses a certain integral to this end.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward for an algebraic function (I think I can do it). Maybe also for an algebraic branch point. The difficulty is taking an expression in Mma, composed of "principle values" of function and constructing the corresponding global analytic function. It seems hard to do this in the case of logarithmic branch points.

Answer (score 2):

An undocumented command ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints works here:

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[Sqrt[(z - a)*(z - b)], z]
```

> `{a, b, ComplexInfinity}`

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[Log[(z - 1)/(z + 1)], z]
```

> `{-1, 1}`

despite your suggestion about a branch point at  `z == (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2`.

Addition. The following can be done, making use of of the integral from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point).

```
ContourIntegrate[D[Log[z - 1/z + 1], z]/Log[z - 1/z + 1], 
z \[Element] Disk[{(-1 + Sqrt[5])/2, 0}, 1/10]]/(2*Pi*I)
```

> `-(ArcTan[\[Pi]/Log[890/(244 + 55 Sqrt[5])]]/\[Pi])`

and

```
ContourIntegrate[D[Log[z - 1/z + 1], z]/Log[z - 1/z + 1], 
 z \[Element] Disk[{a, b}, 1/10], 
 Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals && a != (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2 || 
   a != (-1 - Sqrt[5])/2 && 
Point[{(-1 + Sqrt[5])/2, 0}] \[NotElement] Disk[{a, b}, 1/10] && 
Point[{(-1 - Sqrt[5])/2, 0}] \[NotElement] Disk[{a, b}, 1/10]]/(2*Pi*I)
```

> `0`

One may ask why  `-(ArcTan[\[Pi]/Log[890/(244 + 55 Sqrt[5])]]/\[Pi])` is not an integer number. My explanation is that the branch cuts of `Log[z - 1/z + 1]` from `z==(-1 +/- Sqrt[5])/2` to `ComplexInfinity` cause it.
The branch cut may be taken from `z==(-1 - Sqrt[5])/2` to `z==(-1 + Sqrt[5])/2` (This is done in Сидоров Ю.В.,Федорюк М.В.,Шабунин М.И.Лекции по теории функций комплексного переменного (in Russian)). In this case the integral would be an integer. More complicated case can be handled too, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[ ContourIntegrate[D[Sqrt[(z - a - b*I)*(z - c - d*I)], z]/
Sqrt[(z - a - b*I)*(z - c - d*I)], 
 z \[Element] Disk[{a, b}, Abs[a + I b - c - I d]/2], 
   Assumptions ->   Abs[a + I b - c - I d] > 0 && {a, b, c, d} \[Element] Reals], Assumptions -> Abs[a + I b - c - I d] > 0]/(2*I*Pi)
```

> `1/2`

Comment: Concening branch points at infinity see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Branch_point) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point).

Comment: The typographical errors in the formula `w[z] = Log[-1/+1]` have been corrected. I am aware of ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints, but it often yield incorrect results, and I have also reviewed your previous related answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289606/69835. Since branch points belong to singularities and zeros, but not vice versa, I intend to first identify singularities and zeros, and then utilize the definition of branch points to exclude non-branch points.

Comment: ComplexAnalysis'BranchPoints[Log[z - 1/z + 1], z] performs `{0, 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), ComplexInfinity}` in accordance with the result of the Maple command `FunctionAdvisor(branch_cuts, log(z-1/z+1), plot = 2.)`.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand the purpose of my question. I am aware that the function ComplexAnalysis'BranchPoints can be used to find branch points, but sometimes the branch points obtained by this function are incorrect. Moreover, it is not the case that branch points cannot be found outside of this function.

Comment: One approach is to first find the zeros and singular points (using specialized functions and code), and then systematically check whether these zeros and singular points satisfy the definition of branch points through a program. My question is how to programmatically check whether these zeros and singular points meet the definition of branch points, in order to make decisions and ultimately obtain all branch points.

Comment: What other `ComplexAnalysis` functions exist?

Comment: @bbgodfrey: For example, ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts.

Comment: @bbgodfrey There are three given by ``?ComplexAnalysis`*``, and they each have usage messages.

Comment: @Goofy: I see five commands BranchCuts,
BranchPoints,
HolomorphicQ,
Poles,
Residue
in 13.3.

Comment: That's why `?` is better than a list. It will give the current info on one's own system. (Or maybe it's an autoload thing?)